# Can banner is implementing in slider or not?

Tags: joomla3.0

I have html of slider with with js and css in working condition, now i have to implement Joomla banners in that slider is it possible or right way ? if not than guide me how to do this or another method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, is possible. In this case you need add your custom code in your template, and the custom code via **override**.

First try to add the HTML and content for example in one **Custom HTML module** for test:

- **Adding JavaScript and CSS to the page** (*add the css in your main css file*)
  https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Adding_JavaScript_and_CSS_to_the_page

By default the component banners has a single call at the same time, you'll have to modify the
 php code and include, for example a cycle to recover more banners or similar.

Here you can find more info:

- [Understanding Output Overrides.](https://docs.joomla.org/Understanding_Output_Overrides)
- [Create an override.](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:How_to_use_the_Template_Manager)